# How to set chrome for best webgl-three.js performance

Tags: google-chrome, three.js, webgl

The same three.js example (buffer geometry lines) has 10 fps at Chrome and 20 at FF. Same with other examples.
How to set Chrome for best performance ? I have search on the web and I have applied all recomended settings 
(I have w xp sp3 )
Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/836832/how-can-i-enable-webgl-in-my-browser